# keycode - error on ctrl key

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm trying to call a function when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. However, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key didn't seem to work.

```
    this.element.onkeydown = function(evt){
        var e = evt || window.event;
        var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        var keys = {
            'shift' : e.shiftKey,
            'ctrl' : e.ctrlKey,
            'alt' : e.altKey,
            'enter' : 13,
        };
        console.log(keys['ctrl'],keys['enter']) //false,13
    }
```

I can't see why my `ctrlKey` is false. Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: So, you expect it to be `true` because you press the `ctrl` key? Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8wc7a/

Comment: I just think that `false` means something went wrong.

Comment: No, `false` means the `ctrl` key is not pressed. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.ctrlKey . *"[...] contains true or false, depending on whether the ctrl key was held down or not, when the event fired."*

Comment: I got it. Thank you @Felix Kling.

Answer (score 1):

`onkeydown` is going to get fired after each key is pressed (in other words, it's not the preferred method to capture multiple key downs).

To capture multiple keys events, use `keydown` or `keypress`

Also, you'll actually want to capture 10 and 13 keycodes (keycode in Chrome is 10)

```
this.element.keypress(function (e) {                                 
    var keyCode = (e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode);          

    if (keyCode === 10 || keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
        console.log('success');
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without an **explanation** is not generally very helpful.